# How to disable unnecessary metadata in YII framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need help. How to disable unnecessary metadata of find() methods results in YII framework.
I don't want to save this terrible dirt in session or in client (javascript). I only need to save clear model attributes array in session or transfer this array to client.
How can i solve my problem?
Thanks.

P.S:
$model->attributes does't work for me because i do some relational query.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use a criteria for finding your model, and in criteria apply your limitation or select the fields you only need.

if you want to unset a models attributes, you can do this:

$model->unsetAttributes();